# Disprove that for all integers $a,b$ that if $d=gcd(a,b)$ then $d=gcd(a^2,b)$ or $d=gcd(a,b^2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

***Question:***
Disprove that for all integers $a,b$ that if $d=gcd(a,b)$ then $d=gcd(a^2,b)$ or $d=gcd(a,b^2)$

***Attempts.***

I thought to first try $a=b$, then $d=a$ and $gcd(a^2,b)=b=d$

Ok, how about $a=0, b \neq 0$, then $d=b$ and $gcd(a^2,b)=b=d$

Ok, if $a,b$ are co-prime, then the $d=1$ and $gcd(a^2,b)=1$

Ok, maybe $a=b^2$, then $d=b$ and $gcd(a^2,b)=b$

Not sure what else to try. Maybe the problem is wrong? I copied it down carefully. Hints appreciated.

Comment: $a=12, b=18, d=6$

Comment: @StinkingBishop what was your thought process for choosing $a,b$, that they are both multiples of $6$ ?

Comment: I chose them to be $a=p^2q$ and $b=pq^2$ for two primes $p,q$. This will give me $(a,b)=pq$ and $(a^2, b)=(p^4q^2, pq^2)=pq^2$ and, similarly, $(a, b^2)=(p^2q, p^2q^4)=p^2q$. $6$ is a red herring: $2$ and $3$ are just the smallest primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take two different primes $p,q$ and then set $a=p^2q$ and $b=pq^2$. This will give you:

- $d=(a,b)=pq$
- $(a^2, b)=(p^4q^2, pq^2)=pq^2$,
- $(a, b^2)=(p^2q, p^2q^4)=p^2q$.

For example, for $p=2, q=3$ you will have $a=12, b=18$.

Answer (score 2):

$a=12$, $b=18$.

$gcd(a,b)=6$, but $gdc(a,b^2)=gdc(12,18^2)=12$ and $gdc(a^2,b)=gdc(12^2,18)=18$